# Effects of 'Select = TRUE' on covariates in GAM

Tags: r, regularization, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I'm modelling binary ecological data using a GAMM and I'm having trouble understanding what the 'Select = TRUE' option is doing. As I understand it, 'Select = TRUE' is meant to add extra penalization to all smooths in the model (i.e. lower EDF of covariates and sometimes knocking them out of the model entirely), but I'm seeing something different (I think).

Without 'Select = TRUE', covariate "ToD" has an EDF=1 (linear) and "sal" isn't significant (partial effect includes 0 for all values of "sal" - so, not surprising), however when I include 'Select = TRUE' "sal" becomes statistically significant at the 5% level and "ToD" became more complex (EDF > 1). I thought 'Select = TRUE' was supposed to have the opposite effect, no?

**Questions:**

**1. Does it make sense for the EDF to *increase* for "ToD" when 'Select = TRUE'?**

**2. Why might "sal" (or any covariate) suddenly become significant when 'Select = TRUE'?**

- Unfortunately, I can't share the data.

  ```
  library(mgcv) # gam()/bam()
  library(gratia) # Draw model

    m <- bam(empty ~ s(SL) + # Standard length
               s(temp) + # Temperature
               s(sal) + # Salinity
               s(ToD) + # Time of Day
               s(Longitude, Latitude, bs = 'tp') + # Spatial variation
               s(fStation, bs = "re"), # Structural component
             data = c_neb, 
             method = 'fREML', 
             discrete = TRUE,
             family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
             # select = TRUE, # <----------------- Commented out, so no extra penalization
             gamma = 1.5)

    > summary(m)

    Family: binomial 
    Link function: logit 

    Formula:
    empty ~ s(SL) + s(temp) + s(sal) + s(ToD) + s(Longitude, Latitude, 
        bs = "tp") + s(fStation, bs = "re")

    Parametric coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    (Intercept)  -1.0361     0.1009  -10.27   <2e-16 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

    Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                edf Ref.df Chi.sq  p-value    
    s(SL)                 2.208e+00  2.827 40.534  < 2e-16 ***
    s(temp)               1.000e+00  1.000  1.565    0.211    
    s(sal)                2.151e+00  2.772  4.198    0.185     # <-- Not important
    s(ToD)                1.000e+00  1.000 21.296 4.19e-06 *** # <-- linear, can be Beta*x
    s(Longitude,Latitude) 2.000e+00  2.000  0.599    0.741    
    s(fStation)           2.248e-05 87.000  0.000    0.140    
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

    R-sq.(adj) =  0.0873   Deviance explained = 8.55%
    fREML =  663.8  Scale est. = 1         n = 675

    gratia::draw(m,
             select = c(3,4))
  ```

[image]

```
> gam.check(m)

Method: fREML   Optimizer: perf chol
$grad
[1]  2.389311e-09 -2.728344e-06  5.702256e-08 -2.188869e-06 -2.135506e-06 -1.828631e-06

$hess
              [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]          [,5]          [,6]
[1,]  3.821533e-01  6.820792e-08  1.072074e-03  2.221002e-09  3.419863e-08 -2.262997e-08
[2,]  6.820792e-08  2.728331e-06  1.032721e-07  2.103272e-13 -2.375648e-14 -2.492040e-13
[3,]  1.072074e-03  1.032721e-07  4.014991e-01  9.875683e-09 -1.009651e-07 -5.703817e-08
[4,]  2.221002e-09  2.103272e-13  9.875683e-09  2.188850e-06  6.934220e-14 -7.427936e-13
[5,]  3.419863e-08 -2.375648e-14 -1.009651e-07  6.934220e-14  2.135500e-06 -8.949452e-13
[6,] -2.262997e-08 -2.492040e-13 -5.703817e-08 -7.427936e-13 -8.949452e-13  1.828635e-06

Model rank =  156 / 156 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

                            k'      edf k-index p-value  
s(SL)                 9.00e+00 2.21e+00    0.94   0.095 .
s(temp)               9.00e+00 1.00e+00    0.96   0.215  
s(sal)                9.00e+00 2.15e+00    0.91   0.020 *
s(ToD)                9.00e+00 1.00e+00    0.97   0.365  
s(Longitude,Latitude) 2.90e+01 2.00e+00    0.97   0.270  
s(fStation)           9.00e+01 2.25e-05      NA      NA  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

With 'Select = TRUE' back in

```
 m2 <- bam(empty ~ s(SL) +
               s(temp) + 
               s(sal) + 
               s(ToD) +
               s(Longitude, Latitude, bs = 'tp') + 
               s(fStation, bs = "re"),
             data = c_neb, 
             method = 'fREML', 
             discrete = TRUE, # speed benefit
             family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
             select = TRUE,
             gamma = 1.5)
    
    > summary(m2)
    
    Family: binomial 
    Link function: logit 
    
    Formula:
    empty ~ s(SL) + s(temp) + s(sal) + s(ToD) + s(Longitude, Latitude, 
        bs = "tp") + s(fStation, bs = "re")
    
    Parametric coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    (Intercept) -1.05872    0.09481  -11.17   <2e-16 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                edf Ref.df Chi.sq  p-value    
    s(SL)                 1.990e+00      9 35.705  < 2e-16 ***
    s(temp)               2.353e-01      9  0.462   0.1518    
    s(sal)                1.560e+00      9  4.783   0.0345 *   # <- Became significant, but partial eff. still includes zero
    s(ToD)                1.697e+00      9 19.856 3.82e-06 *** # <- EDF increased
    s(Longitude,Latitude) 1.172e-05     29  0.000   0.6293    
    s(fStation)           2.908e-05     89  0.000   0.1753    
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    R-sq.(adj) =  0.0884   Deviance explained = 8.41%
    fREML = 660.83  Scale est. = 1         n = 675

    gratia::draw(m2,
                 select = c(3,4))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong to assume the `select = TRUE` will necessarily result in lower complexity smooths.

The tests in the output of `summary()` can only test the estimated smooth effect against the Null hypothesis of no effect conditional upon all the other smooths and terms in the model. The estimated effect of one smooth will change depending on the other terms in the model and their estimated effects, unless the covariates (and bases) are uncorrelated (orthogonal). In real world data, we rarely if ever will see perfectly uncorrelated covariates.

When you turned on `select = TRUE`, the effects of $f(\texttt{temp}_i)$ and $f(\texttt{Longitude}_i, \texttt{Latitude}_i)$ are effectively reduced to null effects (flat, constant functions) as the extra penalty on those two smooths has caused them to be shrunk out of the model. As those terms no longer explain variation in the response, there is opportunity for the other smooths to now explain that variation previously explained by the two shrunken smooths. This is perhaps what has happened with $f(\texttt{tod}_i)$.

The other effect that shrinking terms out of the model can have is that it can reduce the uncertainty in the estimates of the remaining terms in the model. This seems to be what has happened with $f(\texttt{sal}_i)$; note the effect has changed shape slightly but that the credible interval is narrower at the boundaries of the `sal` covariate

Comment: Great, thank you for the correction! Does the fact that the partial-effect @ zero (which I think is the "average/no" effect line) on the y-axis of the plot remaining within the confidence interval for all values of sal tell you more than the p-value; that perhaps the p-value isn't to be trusted and sal actually isn't having that much effect?

Comment: You shouldn't interpret the credible interval that way. The *p* values are approximate, and don't account for the fact that we treated the smoothing parameter(s) as known but in actuality selected them from the data, but the posterior distribution of $f(\texttt{sal}_i)$ smooth doesn't really include a flat function at the gran mean of the response.